# suggestions needed to resolve issue with phpmyadmin not working after install

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here. I have a website xxxxx.com on one server and a subdomain of app.xxxxx.com on another server, both with SSL and working fine.

I have just installed phpmyadmin on app.xxxxx.com server and all seems to have went well with the install. However when I visit app.xxxxx.com/phpmyadmin which is where I would expect it to be i get a HTTP500 error "this page isn't working".

I think might be a virtual host/apache routing issue but not too sure?

Comment: Check the webserver log may help? A 500 error is TOO general to know without more context.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good place to start ! Logs showed me that phpmyadmin is not compatible with PHP7.4